# Std::forward and template type deduction

Tags: c++, forward, forwarding-reference

i have written the following little program to understand how std::forward works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
void foo3(T&& bar){
    std::cout<<"foo3&&"<<std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void foo3(T& bar){
    std::cout<<"foo3&"<<std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void foo(T&& bar){
    std::cout<<"foo&&"<<std::endl;
    foo3(std::forward<T>(bar));
}

template<class T>
void foo(T& bar){
    std::cout<<"foo&"<<std::endl;
    foo3(std::forward<T>(bar));
}

int main(int argc, char * argv []){
    int i = 1;
    foo(2);
    foo(i);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the following output:

```
"foo&&"
"foo3&&"
"foo&"
"foo3&"
```

However, I get the following result, which I can't explain:

```
"foo&&"
"foo3&&"
"foo&"
"foo3&&"
```

So if foo is invoked with an lvalue, I expect that foo will forward the lvalue and invoke foo3's lvalue version. However all the time foo3(T&&) is called. Did I understand something completely wrong about how std::forward works or is there a subtle bug? Or even worse, should the code work as I expected and maybe I messed up my compiler implementation?
Btw.I'm using g++ 7.2

Comment: `std::forward` is meant to be used with forwarding references, which `T&` is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did I understand something completely wrong about how std::forward works

Yes. `std::forward` is for forwarding references, and `bar` in `void foo(T&)` is not. If you don't respect this, you will get some strange behavior.

To understand why you'll need to understand what `std::forward` actually does. It is just a cast

```
static_cast<T&&>(t)
```

Where `t` is the argument to `std::forward`. So, the final call of `foo` looks like this:

```
std::cout<<"foo&"<<std::endl;
foo3(std::forward<int>(bar));
```

`T` is deduced to `int`, and if look at the cast, you'll see that it casts `bar` to an rvalue reference, instead of an lvalue reference like you expected.

Comment: I'd describe `std::forward` as a *conditional cast* when applied on forward reference.

Comment: Ah, for sure. It's that easy, i felt there was something wrong. std::forward<decltype(bar)>(bar) should work as expected.

Comment: @Hatatister Well yes. But I'd call that a tricky workaround. Better to not use `std::forward` on a variable that is not a forwarding reference.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I only used forward on a lvalue_reference to find out how std::forward works on edge cases. I wrote this example to find a bug in a program, where I use forwarding references and std::forward ...